# Ambiguous reference between 'Xamarin.Forms.Label' and 'System.Reflection.Emit.Label'

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm starting my first Xamarin.Forms app in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows.

My StartUp project is firstApp.Droid.

In **MainActivity.cs** in **firstApp.Droid** I have this code:

```
namespace firstApp.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = "firstApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
            LoadApplication (new firstApp.App ());
        }
    }
}
```

In **App.cs** I have this code:

```
public App ()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SensorPage());
    }
```

And in **SensorPage.cs** I have this auto-generated code:

```
public class SensorPage : ContentPage
{
    public SensorPage ()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Hello SensorPage" } //line that causes the error
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the app, I get the error:

> CS0104    'Label' is an ambiguous reference between 'Xamarin.Forms.Label' and 'System.Reflection.Emit.Label'

What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

either remove `using System.Reflection.Emit;` from the top of your SensorPage.cs, or alternately use an explicit namespace for Label:

```
Content = new StackLayout {
            Children = {
                new Xamarin.Forms.Label { Text = "Hello SensorPage" }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Reflection is mostly not required.

Comment: I'm surprised the default template included System.Reflection.Emit.  You may have overridden some default in Visual Studio that is causing it to include it.

Comment: @Jason yeah I didn't know why either, started everything with a fresh install of VS and Xamarin. For future Forms users this question maybe is very useful so thanks for your time.